# Report Builder "Select All"

Tags: ssrs, reporting

I have SSRS Report that is based on user's decision to bring data from selected Procedure.

I have 5 parameters:

> @Country, @StartDate, @EndDate, @MinLenght, MaxLenght

When user Selects Just one value we have report like this [![enter image description here][1]][1]

It's my first try. As you can see there is Country Parameter called France, When I try to choose 3 country like

> France, Germany, Italy

Builder gives me an error such as: [![enter image description here][2]][2]

I have DataSet's for each Parameter, If any other query needed in my project I can update it, Here is my Procedure for Report Body

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[GET_SalesByCountryTier1]
(
@Country AS VARCHAR(30),
@Startdate AS DateTIME,
@EndDate AS Datetime,
@MinLenght as INT,
@MaxLenght as INT

)



AS
BEGIN

SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM [DBCenter].[dbo].[VW_FactInternetSales] 
    WHERE Country IN (@Country) AND Orderdate BETWEEN @Startdate AND @EndDate) AS SalesCount,
(SELECT SUM(TaxAmt) FROM [DBCenter].[dbo].[VW_FactInternetSales] 
    WHERE Country = @Country AND Orderdate BETWEEN @Startdate AND @EndDate) AS TotalTaxAmt,
(SELECT AVG(ProductStandardCost) FROM [DBCenter].[dbo].[VW_FactInternetSales]
    WHERE Country = @Country AND Orderdate BETWEEN @Startdate AND @EndDate) AS Cost,
(SELECT AVG(TaxAmt) FROM [DBCenter].[dbo].[VW_FactInternetSales] 
    WHERE Country = @Country AND Orderdate BETWEEN @Startdate AND @EndDate) AS AvgTax,
(SELECT AVG(ProductStandardCost) FROM DBCenter.dbo.VW_FactInternetSales 
    WHERE Country = @Country AND OrderDate BETWEEN @Startdate and @EndDate AND ProductStandardCost >= @MinLenght AND ProductStandardCost < @MaxLenght ) AS MinLenght

END
```

UPDATE

My Code in DataSet for Parameter: `SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM DBCenter.dbo.VW_FactInternetSales WHERE Country IN ('France', 'Germany', 'Italy')`
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4y5Q.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTWzv.png

Comment: Any chance you use your `County` report parameter in an SSRS expression somewhere in the report?...or anything similar on the report side?

Comment: I have @Country in My DataSet Query, is that what you mean?

Comment: No I mean do you use it anywhere else in your report with additional logic? This is what [expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/expression-examples-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15) are in SSRS.

Comment: Also can you please post screenshots of your [Report Parameters Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-parameters-report-builder-and-report-designer?view=sql-server-ver15#bkmk_Report_Parameters)? It's *possible* the issue is somewhere in how those are configured, but not sure.

Comment: @J.D. I have edited my Question, You can see it in there as image

Comment: Thanks, I think some of your links might be missing or broken. Specifically seeing the General tab would be helpful.

Comment: I still have the problem but no problem